# CSS texte and image alignement in %

Tags: html, css

I'm a real beginner in CSS...
Do you know how could I do this sort of alignment ? I try a lot a things but I don't get what I need... So I just draw it if you have any code idea...

```html
<div id="sys-wrap">
  <img src="image.png">
  <p>Long message texte</p>
</div>
```

```css
#sys-wrap {}    
#sys-wrap p {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  float:left;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 691px;
}
#sys-wrap img {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 100px; 
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/f1501914cc.jpg))</sub>

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Are you looking to align the image to the right and wrap text around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle. Does this work for you?

https://jsfiddle.net/hnf8jou4/3/

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div id="left">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" id="inner">
  </div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
  width:25%;
  height:200px;
  float: left;
  background-color:#f00;
}

#right {
  width:75%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#0f0;
}
#inner {
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

Comment: It seems very nice, but the paragraph text on the right is going under the image as there is a lot of text. How t make to text stay in the green div you setup?

Comment: We are very very close. I need to add some margin-right or padding-right space to the "right" ID... but the code I set isn't working. It ignores my margin-right and padding-right... any idea? -EDIT- solved by adding an extra div upper and padding global. Thanks for your help! Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

It is really unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. But since i saw the drawing u made i suppose this is what u need. U need to have a div for wrap and add `float: right` to the right `div`. The other things are just playing with height in % and paddings.

https://jsfiddle.net/hnf8jou4/4/

Answer (score 0):

For `#sys-wrap img` inside of your CSS file, add a `float: right;` and a `margin` of `15px`

Your new CSS should look similar to this:

```
#sys-wrap img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  float: right;
  margin: 15px; 
}
```

Also, give it's parent container a set width and height:

```
#sys-wrap {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red; // just to make it pretty
}
```

And just as a little fyi, `vertical-align` does not work, unless the specified element has a `display` of `table-cell`. :-)

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d2ae3ub3/